# Importing data from .txt file

Tags: matlab, import

I have a .txt file with the following content:

```
Start Time: 1/9/2020 4:41:09 PM
Sample Rate: 256
Unit: 

Data:
-800
-800
-573
```

What is the right way to import it preserving the "structure" structure?

Required output is somthing like:

```
output = struct('Start Time', '1/9/2020 4:41:09 PM', 'Sample Rate', '256', ... 
'Unit', '', 'Data', ['-800', '-800', '-573']);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "right way"? For example you could just read the text file line by line and parse it yourself or you could try to use some csv importer and maybe skip some lines.

Comment: In my opinion, right way is using matlab's tools such as readtable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `textscan` to import unformatted data (just one string per line), using the format specifier `%s`. After that you need to subdivide that string into your struct e.g. like this:

```
fid=fopen('test.txt');
data_raw=textscan(fid,'%s', 'Delimiter','');
data_raw=data_raw{1};
begin_time=strfind(data_raw{1},': ');
begin_rate=strfind(data_raw{2},': ');
begin_unit=strfind(data_raw{3},': ');
data_struct=struct('start_time',data_raw{1}((begin_time+2):end),...
    'sample_rate',str2num(data_raw{2}((begin_rate+2):end)),...
    'unit',data_raw{3}((begin_rate+2):end),...
    'data',str2num(cell2mat(data_raw(5:end))));
```

Comment: does this method work if I want to preserve the sampling rate?

Comment: @GideonKogan What do you mean by "preserve the sampling rate"? Please edit your question to include an example output, you would like to achieve. If you want something like first row="Sampling rate: 256" and after that numerical data, that will require a cell array, which will make processing of the data a lot harder. Maybe you should consider storing the sampling rate seperately. Would a `struct` with two fields (`samle_rate` and `data`) be an option?

Comment: @GideonKogan Is this what you wanted?

Comment: I have been looking for a build-in function. It is not what I wanted but probably it is the best we can do, Thank you for your effort

Comment: @GideonKogan Well, the format of your data is very unique. It's not possible for matlab or any other tool to guess how exactly you want your data to be structured. Therefor there can not be a built-in to apply exactly your individual format. There might be a more elegant way to implement this, but it will not be a one-liner, if that's what you were looking for. This can, however, be extended to dynamically extract an arbitrary amount of fields depending on the text-file.